# Validation for Rate component ant.design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to validate Rate component, set initial value, etc.

```
  {getFieldDecorator('rating', {
    initialValue: dataSource.getIn(['data', 'rating'], ''),
    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Field is required' }],
  })(<Rate allowClear={false} onChange={this.setRating} />)}
```

Having code like this in my form result in an error after each value change

> Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`, so please don't
>   set `value` directly and use `setFieldsValue` to set it.

Any ideas how to overcome it?
Code works as expected

Comment: yeah,,, same theme.. don't mutate `state` directly, rather use `setState`.. :)

Comment: I don't use states at all

Comment: this.setRating source?

Comment: this.setRating = value => props.onSet({ path: 'detail.data.rating', data: value }); 
it's redux action

Comment: Are you setting `defaultValue`?

Comment: defaultValue? No. This code usually works like a default value
  `initialValue: dataSource.getIn(['data', 'rating'], '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate `<Rate />` in `antd design` you should use `null` as initial value.

```
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator('rating', {
        initialValue: review.rating ? review.rating:null,
        rules: [
            {   
                required: true,
                message:'Rating Required',
            },
        ],
    })(
        <Rate />,
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because you should not use `onChange` when your component is being controlled by the `Form`

if you would want to get the actual rate using:
`this.props.form.validateFields()` since will be also do the field validation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include

1. required validation
2. minimum number validation, otherwise user can submit with a zero rating.

```
<Form.Item
  label="How satisfied are you"
  name="rating"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Please provide a rating.",
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      min: 0.5,
      message: "Please provide a rating.",
    },
  ]}
>
  <Rate allowHalf />
</Form.Item>;
```